Flutter - How to make omitted widget with grid UI

Flutter noob here,
trying to make a photo grid UI exactly the picture above.
There must be only 3 boxes positioned and consider each box is a photo card.
If I got 4 pictures, the bottom right dimmed box shows +1, if 5, then shows +2 and so on.
No less than 3, minumim 4, only have to deal with the 3 boxes with exact same grid layout(the screenshot above) and the number(on the dimmed box).
Not so sure to present list with omitting it.
Thanks in advance.

For this type pd grid check flutter_staggerd_grid_view package

you can use the GridView.count Here is the code you can try to implement it.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Photo Grid',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> images = [
    'image1.jpg',
    'image2.jpg',
    'image3.jpg',
    // Add more images as needed
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Photo Grid'),
      ),
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        children: List.generate(3, (index) {
          if (index < images.length) {
            return PhotoCard(image: images[index]);
          } else if (index == 3) {
            return OverflowBox(
              minWidth: 100.0,
              minHeight: 100.0,
              maxWidth: 150.0,
              maxHeight: 150.0,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '+${images.length - 3}',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return SizedBox.shrink();
          }
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhotoCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image;

  const PhotoCard({Key key, this.image}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(image),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


